# Removing /index.php/ from url breaks site

Tags: admin, index

When I try the solution mentioned [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/remove-index.php), my site breaks, pages not found. Even the `/admin/` pages break, losing all styling. The only page which loads is the homepage.

Any thoughts about why? I was having htaccess issues, but I believe those are all fixed now.

This is the htaccess file in the the top level craft folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

There is the root: 
`brianfeeney.us/`

Which contains both:
`brianfeeney.us/blog` (WP)
`brianfeeney.us/craft`

The index.php in my root points towards `/blog/`

thanks for the help

Comment: Can you share the .htaccess file you're using in your public HTML folder?

Comment: I don't have an .htaccess file in the public folder. Should I? The /public and /craft folders are both in the same folder (brianfeeney.us/craft/..).    This is the htaccess file in the the top level craft folder           `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Can you edit the original question and add that as well as what your folder structure looks like?  Pretty hard to read as code in the comments.

Comment: Is there any .htaccess file at the root of brianfeeney.us? If so, .htaccess rules inherit from their parent so one of those could be interfering with Craft's.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you figured it out however, I just found adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

right under RewriteEngine On fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, I think the problem is that your `.htaccess` is not in the webroot. try putting it in the same dir as `web.config`.

Also bare in mind that there are two `.htaccess`, the other is in /craft dir, and that one should stay there and not edited.